# How to answer Canadian Visa Eligibility question regarding employment?

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas

I'm a non-US student studying in the US (an "international student" on an F1 visa), and would like to apply for a Canadian Visitor Visa (I believe it's a.k.a. a Temporary Visit Visa). I'm going through the eligibility check on their site, and one of the question is whether I have a job. If I'm employed on-campus by my university only, should I respond 'Yes' (this is a yes/no question)? I suspect that I should.

Here's a screenshot of the question:

[image]

EDIT: I do get paid for this on-campus employment.

Comment: I don't think on-campus or off-campus matters to that question. You do have a job and you do get paid, I would answer Yes

Answer (score 1):

You do have a job and you do get paid. End of story. Select 'Yes' and proceed.